# Keeping track of MVVM Light messengers in complex program

Tags: .net, debugging, mvvm, mvvm-light, messenger

Messenger is very useful for communicating between viewmodels. However, as program grows larger, the use of messenger will make the code unreadable and hard to debug.

Is there a good way to keep track of messages registered and sent?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static class that you'll do the sending through (or extend the messenger).
Add to it logging if you want, and some methods to check what is registered and what was send ...
Not sure why you would need this, but it's an option ...